# Android-Java-Map-Location -Show current location in photo capturing in offline mode

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

*Background / Concept*: I want to create an application that can help user take a photo and attach with location even the devices is in offline(no internet connection).As user I want to get location of photo I took so that I could get location even if I went to rural area without internet coverage.

Problem: 
1. Is it possible to indicate current user position of photos if there is no internet coverage?
2.If I can get offline photo location For example, if I took a picture at Phnom penh(this place no internet) for a user, and then we upload it 10 min later in Kandal(this place have internet), does the photo show Phnom penh or Kandal?

Answer (score 0):

*if I took a picture at Phnom penh(this place no internet) for a user, and then we upload it 10 min later in Kandal(this place have internet), does the photo show Phnom penh or Kandal?*

You can already receive location without internet with GPS provider. But it's not possible to convert from location to address without internet(geocoding). But instead, you can just store lat/lng of current location when you take picture. When the device reaches internet then convert from lat/lng to location.

Comment: Thanks Blackara, It is helpful.